# Why unique_ptr doesn't destroy object immediately when goes out-of-scope?

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code:

```
struct C
{
    C()             {std::cout << ">>> constructor\n"; }
    ~C()            {std::cout << ">>> destructor\n"; }
};

void bar(std::unique_ptr<C>&& p)
{
    std::cout << "bar\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto instance = std::make_unique<C>();
    std::cout << "after construction\n";
    bar(std::move(instance));                // #1
    std::cout << "after bar\n";
    return 0;
}
```

On line **#1**, I'm moving the pointer to the function `bar`. I was thinking that in this call the pointer-to-C is moved-out from `unique_ptr instance` and passed to the argument `unique_ptr p`. If so, then the `C` destructor should be called at the end of `bar()`'s execution when argument `p` is destructed. But it turned out that the instance of `C` is alive until the end of `main()`' s execution. The output looks as follows:

```
>>> constructor
after construction
bar
after bar
>>> destructor
```

Why does it happen? How to interpret this behavior?

Comment: Try removing && from bar

Comment: Than try thinking of && as & with extra information about what you can do with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::move` doesn't actually move. It just casts it into a an rvalue reference.

Change

```
void bar(std::unique_ptr<C>&& p)
```

to

```
void bar(std::unique_ptr<C> p)
```

To actually do the move in the move constructor.

Comment: Or `bar` could do something like `std::unique_ptr<C> x(std::move(p))`, that would move too.